# What happens when I leave xmlns:android out?

Tags: android, compilation, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I was digging around my android project and found that one of my style.xml files was missing the namespace statement: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`. However, this doesn't look like it caused any error (so far). It brings me to wonder if there is a necessity to include the namespace or is it just there as safety check?

Comment: You need the namespace if any attributes in the file use the namespace prefix. In your case, presumably the file does not have any `android:` attributes, and so the namespace would be superfluous.

Comment: @CommonsWare After taking a second look, you are right; I am not using any `android:` attributes. Thanks for the pointing this out! I do have something like `<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">`, but I'm guessing that is irrelevant to the namespace declaration.

Comment: Yes, the namespace is on the attribute name (e.g., `android:showAsAction` in a menu resource). Anything that happens to use `android:` as part of the syntax of a value is not part of the XML namespace system. If you remove the XML namespace statement from an XML file that *does* use `android:` for attribute names, you will probably get a build error somewhere along the line.